# Switching to macOS Login Window with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-sonoma

Since the 'Other User' option from the Login Window is not available for network accounts on the Lock Screen of macOS 14, I'm trying to create a workaround.

It seems to be possible to use AppleScript to switch to the Login Window via the user switcher menu. I tried to write a script but didn't fully succeed yet. The following examples do click and show the user switcher but I have not find out how to actually click the 'Login Window...' option then.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events" to tell process "ControlCenter"
    click menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
    click its menu bar item "Login Window"
end tell
```

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "ControlCenter"
        tell its menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
            click
                tell its menu item 3
                    click
                end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
    tell its application process "ControlCenter"
        tell its menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
            click
            tell its window "UserSwitcher"
                tell its group 2
                    set btns to its buttons
                    if name of btn = "Login Window..." then
                        click btn
                    end if
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events" to tell process "ControlCenter"
    click menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
end tell
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "ControlCenter"
    tell menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Login Window..." of menu 2
    end tell
end tell
```

I hope to find some help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Control Center is obviously written in SwiftUI. There are no accessible UI elements

Comment: A-ha. So it’s not possible this way?